# Spring Batch - Job executions launching with same Task execution id

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-task

I'm using Spring Batch with Spring Cloud Task for remote partitioning. But for each new Job execution it is created with the same task execution id. Is there any way to create a new task execution id for new job execution?

[image: task_task_batch table]

In the following Task Execution table, each job is running with same parent execution id.

[image: Task Execution Table]

For each new job execution it is starting within the same task execution. The code for Batch configuration is as follows:

```
@Bean
public PartitionHandler partitionHandler(TaskLauncher taskLauncher, JobExplorer jobExplorer, Environment environment, DelegatingResourceLoader delegatingResourceLoader, TaskRepository taskRepository) {
    Resource resource = delegatingResourceLoader.getResource(jarLocation);
    
    DeployerPartitionHandler partitionHandler = new DeployerPartitionHandler(taskLauncher, jobExplorer, resource, "workerStep", taskRepository);
    List<String> commandLineArguments = new ArrayList<>(5);
    commandLineArguments.add("--spring.profiles.active=worker");
    commandLineArguments.add("--spring.cloud.task.initialize.enable=false");
    commandLineArguments.add("--spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false");
    commandLineArguments.add("--spring.cloud.task.closecontext_enabled=true");
    commandLineArguments.add("--logging.level=DEBUG");
    
    partitionHandler.setCommandLineArgsProvider(new PassThroughCommandLineArgsProvider(commandLineArguments));
    partitionHandler.setEnvironmentVariablesProvider(new SimpleEnvironmentVariablesProvider(environment));
    partitionHandler.setMaxWorkers(2);
    partitionHandler.setApplicationName("BatchApplicationWorker");
    return partitionHandler;
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public Partitioner partitioner(@Value("#{jobParameters['inputFiles']}") String file, @Value("#{jobParameters['partitionSize']}") String partitionSize1){
    int partitionSize = Integer.parseInt(partitionSize1);
    return new Partitioner() {
        public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
            Map<String, ExecutionContext> partitions = new HashMap<>();
            String[] ids = fetchAllPrimaryKeys(file); 
            List<List<String>> partitionPayloads = splitPayLoad(ids, partitionSize);
            int size = partitionPayloads.size();
            for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
                ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
                executionContext.put("partitionNumber", i);
                executionContext.put("partitionPayLoad", new ArrayList<>(partitionPayloads.get(i)));
                partitions.put("partition" + i, executionContext);
            }
            return partitions;
        }
    };
}


@Bean
public Step masterStep(Step workerStep, PartitionHandler partitionHandler) {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep")
            .partitioner(workerStep.getName(), partitioner(null, null))
            .step(workerStep)
            .partitionHandler(partitionHandler)
            .build();
}


@Bean
public Step workerStep(CustomWriter customWriter, CustomProcessor customProcessor) {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("workerStep")
            .<User,User>chunk(10000)
            .reader(reader(null))
            .processor(customProcessor)
            .writer(customWriter)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Job batchJob(Step masterStep, JobExecutionListnerClass jobExecutionListnerClass, JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("batchJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(masterStep)
            .listener(jobExecutionListnerClass)
            .build();


public Long jobRunner(JobParams jobParams) throws BatchException {
    Map<String, JobParameter> maps = new HashMap<>();
    maps.put(Constants.TIME, new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    maps.put(Constants.INPUT_FILES, new JobParameter(jobParams.getInputSource()));
    maps.put(Constants.PARTITION_SIZE, new JobParameter(Integer.toString(jobParams.getPartitionSize())));
    maps.put(Constants.MAIL_RECIPIENTS, new JobParameter(jobParams.getMailRecipients()));
    maps.put(Constants.JOB_NAME, new JobParameter(jobParams.getJobName()));
    maps.put(Constants.JOB_DESCRIPTION, new JobParameter(jobParams.getJobDescription()));
    maps.put(Constants.JOB_RESTART, new JobParameter(Boolean.toString(jobParams.getRestart())));
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(maps);
    JobExecution jobExecution;
    try {
        jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException
            | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
        throw new BatchException(e.getMessage());
    }
    return jobExecution.getId();
}
```

Comment: Please share more details about your setup and how you launch tasks/jobs.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine added batch configuration

Comment: You did not share how you run tasks. The typical case is to run a task instance for each partitioned job instance.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Isn't DeployerPartitionHandler responsible for launching new worker nodes as task for partitioned job?